# Ajax Missing in Laravel Project

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I built the following...

```
<script>
    $('#spielAuswahl').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);

        var spielID = e.target.value;

        //ajax
        $get.('/spieler?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I get this issue...

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

```
$get.('/spieler?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){
```

Could it be because there is no Ajax implemented in my project? When it is so, I'm using Laravel. How do I add Ajax to Laravel? Are there online libraries for Ajax for an easy, quick implementation?

Comment: just replace `$get.(` with `$.get(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX wouldn't be missing unless you forgot to include jQuery. The error seems pretty straight forward in that it cannot parse the syntax. You have the $ and period swapped. Change your call to this

```
//ajax
$.get('/spieler?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

If using Laravel 5.4 and Laravel Mix, out of the box it includes axios, which you can also use. Check your **resources/js/app.js** and **resources/js/boostrap.js** files first to see if it is there before trying

```
//ajax
axios.get('/spieler?spielID=' + spielID).then(function(response){
   console.log(response);
});
```